# Cannot sample GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in the Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader

I have a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY which I create with empty data then give to the compute shader to calculate some values, this works fine I get the values in the texture that I want.

Now I'm trying to read that data in the fragment shader to produce some output, I pass it in like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "textureSampler"), 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureID);
```

Then I call glDrawElements to draw a quad. Within the fragment shader itself I have the code:

```
uniform sampler2DArray textureSampler;
```

Then I perform a test to see if the texture has successfully been passed into the shader:

```
vec4 test = texture(textureSampler, ivec3(0,0,0));

if (test == vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0))
{
    color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

And I end up with a red quad meaning that the result of the texture lookup is vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) which is not what it should be based on the values I write in the compute shader and the testing I do afterwards. I've checked and every single texel is the same so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong in the passing of the texture can anyone spot what it is?

Comment: Are you calling `glUseProgram(programID)` before setting the uniform? Also you may need to call `glMemoryBarrier` between using your compute shader and calling `glDrawElements`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions, I do currently do both with the argument for `glMemoryBarrier` being `GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT` is this the correct one? In the compute shader I update the texture using `imageStore`

Comment: From my understanding of http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMemoryBarrier the correct flag is `GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT​` (but I could be wrong). You could try using `GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS​` to see whether it's anything to do with synchronization at all.

Comment: Yeah I tried both of those still get the problem so i guess its to do with something else

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted. One thing to try (complete guess here) is make sure you're not trying to read from a mipmap level you haven't created (set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`).

Comment: Already doing that, yeah it must be something really stupid that I can't spot